# Pyplot: display oldest plot first

Tags: python, matplotlib

In my Python project I have several functions that create figures with `plt.figure()`. After calling all these functions, I call `plt.show()`and all my plots are displayed correctly, but in reverse order of creation, so the one I see first is the last one that was created, and the 1st one created is at the back. How can I reverse this order of appearance?

UPDATE: this seems to happen only on Mac OSX, using Python from VS code. On Linux, the plots appear on the same order as they were created, which is what I want.